# How to use preg_replace to add one hour to a time value?

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a page that shows times on it like this: `10:00am`. I need to take those times, and add one hour to them. I have come up with a regular expression to deal with finding the times themselves, I just don't know what to do next. This is the regex I have: `^(1[012]|[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])(?i)(am|pm)^`.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. -Austin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, don't need any regexes:

```
$time = '10:00am';
list($hour, $min) = explode(':', $time);
echo date('h:ia', mktime((int)$hour + 1, (int)$min));
```

Casting to `int` gets rid of the trailing `am` so that the minutes part can be used in `mktime`.

If you *need* to use the regex (for example, you are searching for times inside a larger string), you can use this:

```
preg_match('~^(1[012]|[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])(?i)(am|pm)^~', $str, $matches);
echo date('h:ia', mktime($match[1] + 1, $match[2]));
```

And, if you need to *replace* those times inside the original string, you can use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$time = preg_replace_callback('~(1[012]|[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])(?i)(am|pm)~', 
            function($matches) {
                return date('h:ia', mktime($matches[1] + 1, $matches[2]));
            },
        $time);
```

Version for PHP 5.2 and older:

```
$time = preg_replace_callback('~(1[012]|[1-9]):([0-5][0-9])(?i)(am|pm)~', 
            create_function(
                '$matches',
                'return date(\'h:ia\', mktime($matches[1] + 1, $matches[2]));'
            },
        $time);
```

Comment: Thank you. The last thing you posted finally worked for me. I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can help now, but I have a slight problem. I tested the last method you posted on both my development servers (PHP version 5.3.1 and 5.3.5) and it worked on both. However, when i uploaded the file to the production server (PHP version 5.2.13) it has a parse error (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION...)

Comment: Yup, lambda functions aren't supported in 5.2. You must use `create_function()` instead of a normal function. Take a look at the PHP manual for `preg_replace_callback` for an example.

Comment: I also updated my answer to include a version with `create_function`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use this one-liner: `echo date("h:ia", strtotime("10:43am +1 hour"));`, replace 10:43 with an interpolated variable and make sure it's parsable by `strtotime()` (your example format is).

Answer (score 1):

Parse the time to "part" variables, perform your modifications, and put the parts back into a new string.

For example:

```
$time = '10:00am';
$time = substr($time, 0, 5);
$ampm = substr($time, 6);
list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $time);

// do your thing

$newtime = sprintf('%02d:%02d%s', $hours, $minutes, $ampm);
```