# trying to expand a regex and related function

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex that is compatible with time in the following formats: `12:30am, 2:45pm`. I need the regex to be compatible with this format: `5pm` as well as the preceding formats. I also have a function that needs to work with this:

```
$time = preg_replace_callback($regex, create_function('$matches', 'return ltrim(date("H:i", mktime($matches[1] + 1, $matches[2])), "0").$matches[3];'), $time);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. -Austin

Comment: Why don't you use any of the non regexp solutions given to your previous question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230636/how-to-use-preg-replace-to-add-one-hour-to-a-time-value ), when you wouldn't need to worry about these variations in format?

Comment: @Mark Baker: this is the page i am working on. maybe if you look at it, you will understand why i can't use non regex solutions, or you can help me understand how i can use them. http://redsphere.co.cc/radio.php

Comment: If you already have a regex, then adapt it. Use [regular-expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info/) to learn the syntax or one of [the tools that help designing regexps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) doesn't work for you. Why all the regex craziness?

```
echo date( "H:i", strtotime("5pm"));     // 17:00
echo date( "H:i", strtotime("12am"));    // 00:00
echo date( "H:i", strtotime("12:24pm")); // 12:24
echo date( "H:i", strtotime("4pm"));     // 16:00
echo date( "H:i", strtotime("3:45pm"));  // 15:45
echo date( "H:i", strtotime("11:45pm")); // 23:45
```

Comment: how can I use `strtotime` if i don't already know what the times are going to be? The page is updated regularly, and the times change every time an update occurs (every few minutes).

Comment: `strtotime` takes a formatted time/date string and turns it into a timestamp for use with date. I'm not sure how "changing times" matters here. It's the purpose of this function.

Comment: how can i take something like `5:23pm | artist - song title` and use it with `strtotime`?

Comment: You would need to pull the time out and perform strtotime on the time. If it is exactly formated like that every time, you could explode on " | " to get the time string and `strtotime($ar[0])`;

Comment: @Kevin: sorry it took so long for the accept. I am still relatively new to the site, and I forget to do that.

Comment: Hey no problem. Just wanted to be sure that, if it worked out for you, something was done :)